# Can Player ID returned by Game service be hacked

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have implemented Google Game service in my game, and I want to know if the player ID returned by Game Service can be hacked?

I will use that ID to retrieve player data from a database. I am aware that I can request ID token and use it to verify the player identity by sending it to a server and validate it there. However, requesting ID token will ask the user to allow the app to "Know who you are on Google", and I don't want to show that permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to use is the Server Auth Code.  The flow is:

1. The user signs into your game on the device as normal.  When you
   build the client connection, request ServerAuthCode. to be
   generated.

   ```
   String webclientId = getString(R.string.webclient_id);
   // Request authCode so we can send the code to the server.
   GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions
                     .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                     .requestServerAuthCode(webclientId)
                     .build();


       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
               .addApi(Games.API)
               .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
               .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
               .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               .build();
   ```
2. Get the auth code when sign-in completes and send the auth code to the server.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                               Intent intent) {
   if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
               + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
       GoogleSignInResult result =
               Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);
       if (result.isSuccess()) {
           sendToServer(result.getSignInAccount().getServerAuthCode(););
       } else {
           showSignInError(result.getStatus().getStatusCode());
       }
   ```
3. On the server exchange the auth code for an access token for that user.

   ```
        GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse =
               new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
                       HTTPTransport,
                       JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                       "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                       clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId(),
                       clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret(),
                       authCode,
                       "")
                       .execute();
   ```
4. The server can then verify the access token to get the user's ID
   securely.

   ```
       ApplicationVerifyResponse resp = gamesAPI.applications().verify
           (applicationId).execute();
       Log.d(TAG, "The player id is " + resp.getPlayerId());
   ```

There is a sample that shows how to do this in GitHub: https://github.com/playgameservices/clientserverskeleton